# prove that : $\lim_{n\to +\infty}U_{n}=\operatorname{rationale-number}\iff m=\operatorname{consecutive-natural-numbers}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let the sequence $U_{n}$ , $n\in\mathbb{N^{*}}$

$$\begin{cases}U_{1}=\sqrt[3]{m},m\in\mathbb{N}\\U_{n}=\sqrt[3]{U_{n-1}+m}\end{cases}$$

Then prove that :

> $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}U_{n}=\operatorname{rationale-number}\iff m=\operatorname{consecutive-natural-numbers}$$

Mean that : $m=s(s-1)(s+1)$ for natural number $s$

I can prove the first $\implies$ but the second

$m=s(s-1)(s+1)\implies \lim_{n\to +\infty}U_{n}=\frac{p}{q}$

What must be prove ? I don't know ?

I think prove convergence ? But how

Answer (score 3):

From $U_{n}=f(U_{n-1})$, where $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+m}$, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x+m)^2}}>0$ and $$U_2=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{m}+m}>\sqrt[3]{m}=U_1$$
we conclude that $U_3=f(U_2)\geq(U_1)=U_2$ and (by induction) the sequence is ascending or $U_n\geq U_{n-1}$. It is also not too difficult (by induction) to show that $U_n\leq m$. The sequence is increasing and bounded above, [so it has a limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), which is a solution of 
$$L^3-L=m=s^3-s$$
One possible solution is $L_1=s\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0, 1\}$. The other two possible solutions for $L$'s will have to satisfy $$L^2+Ls+s^2=1$$
leading to
$$L_{2,3}=\frac{-s\pm\sqrt{4-3s^2}}{2}$$
which works for $s=1$, but we agreed $s\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0, 1\}$ to avoid $m=0$ case. In all the other cases $L_{2,3}\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ and can't be limits of a sequence of real numbers. As a result, $L_1=s$ is the only reasonable answer.

$m=0$ is a trivial case.

Comment: Thank you sir @rtybase but ...+1! nice